# Speeding up a Table with NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I have a parametric system of differential equations (a and b are the parameters). For every value of the parameters in a given range I want to find the right initial conditions to fit some observations. With this aim I defined a table which runs over the parameters a and b, and for every parameter I use NMinimize to minimize a chi-square variable over the initial conditions space {x0,vx0,y0,vy0}. I wonder if there is a way to speed up this process. The main part of the code is this:

```
chisquare[x0_?NumberQ, vx0_?NumberQ, y0_?NumberQ, vy0_?NumberQ] := 
1/(70 - 4)
Sum[((1/dx[[i]] (((x[x0, vx0, y0, vy0][t = years[[i]]] /.ss) +(y[x0,vx0, y0, vy0][t = years[[i]]] /. ss)) - xobs[[i]]))^2 + (1/
   dy[[i]] (((x[x0, vx0, y0, vy0][t = years[[i]]] /.ss) + (y[x0, vx0, y0, vy0][t = years[[i]]] /. ss))/
      8.3 - yobs[[i]]))^2), {i, 1, 70}]
Table[{a, b,  NMinimize[chisquare[x0, vx0, y0, vy0][a][b], {{800 < x0 < 1100}, {400 < vx0 < 900},{1350 < y0 < 
1750}, {10 < vy0 < 110}}, {x0, vx0, y0, vy0}][[1]]}, {a,arange}, {b, orange}]
```

where ss is a parametricNDsolve of two equations over {x0,vx0,y0,vy0}

NMinimize takes 146 seconds for a given couple of parameters {a,b}. Do you think there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: The bottleneck will be your code for `chisquare` I think. Can we see it?

Comment: Now I put the expression for chi-square

Comment: You could reduce recalculations. Also use listable properties of +, ^ and / and remove the unnecessary `Sum` and `i` index. Hopefully you can get this to work https://pastebin.com/fCACn9rp but if not, you will need to provide the definitions for y, yobs, x, xobs, dx, dy etc. because I cannot test it without them.